# Autopost the new node after three hours in social networks especially facebook,linkedin and twitter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, social-networking, scheduler

- I am using Drupal for facebook module for autoposting the node in
  facebook page,Linkedin integration module for autoposting in linkedin
  page and twitter module for autoposting in twitter page.It works
  perfectly.

[image]

- I dont want to save the new node immediately in facebook, linkedin,
  twitter page. I want to post the new node after three hours.
- Here am using scheduler module also.The user should not give the date
  and time in scheduler module, it have to post the node after three
  hours automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really used the Scheduler module, but conceptually if the fields for the day and time in scheduler module are available, you can hide it from the user's view using `hook_form_alter` and then use `hook_form_submit` to fill the values for the date and time set to 3 hours after the publish date.

Comment: Thanks.These answer helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well,The only solution to this can be by developing a custom module, integrating those APIs. Also, without running the cron, Drupal will not know what items are in queue. You will need to use an external application developed in node.js which will monitor the entries in the database and will call a function which will post those nodes to respective social networks.

You did not mention that whether you just want to delay the posting on social networks or also want to delay the node publishing.

Comment: ok.I will do it.I want to delay the node publishing after some hourls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem needs a out of the box solution. If i had to solve this i would create a custom module which would create a custom table something like the given below

| Node Id  |  Expiry timestamp  |

I would make a new entry in the same when a new node is created & delete from the table once a node is published on facebook.

I will make a function xyz() which will be set on cron at every minutes interval.

```
function xyz(){
  if(/* check if any rows are there in the table */){
    /*check the time stamp & post onto facebook if time is 3 hours*/
  }
}
```

Also i will make timestamp as a search index of the table so that it improves the perfomance

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution that actually worked was using Rules.

In my case, I wanted to schedule my node (with Scheduler) for a certain date, but Autopost was posting in Facebook immediately. Solution was to create a Rule to react only when node was published by Scheduler.

The good thing about this it that there's no need to fuss about in the code. And it's very extensible.

Hope it helps someone.